Remotely execute on Hyper-V guest from host with admin rights on the guest
How may my Hyper-V host remotely execute an elevated program on its guest running Windows 11?
I'm authoring some tooling to manage a GUI test program on a Hyper-V guest running Windows 11. Ideally this VM will not have network access so I'm trying to avoid approaches such as installing a service on the VM that will listen for commands over the network.
I've discovered that Microsoft has PowerShell commands specifically for Hyper-V and so far I've been able to manage everything else I've needed about the VM. I've also had good success using Windows UI Automation for the GUI testing locally. But I've been having a difficult time executing the GUI test program remotely on the VM. The root of the difficulty appears to be the fact that administrator privileges on the remote target are required in order to remotely launch an application that can interact with the input desktop on the remote target. And so I believe that I need a way to establish a remote PowerShell session into the VM with administrator rights on the VM.
The most promising approach I've tried so far is to copy PsExec onto the VM, then on the host run the PowerShell command New-PSSession (giving it credentials for an administrator account on the VM), then pass that session object into the Enter-Session command, then execute PsExec in that session. But that fails because "The requested operation requires elevation":
PS> New-PSSession -VMName "Windows 11" | Enter-PSSession
[Windows 11]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> .\PsExec.exe .\test.exe -i -h -accepteula
PsExec could not start test.exe:
The requested operation requires elevation.

I see that New-PSSession has a -RunAsAdministrator parameter, but that parameter is only valid with the -ContainerId parameter which is a Docker thing. After digging into Microsoft's source code I can see that ultimately boils down to telling vmcompute.dll to create a process with "RestrictedToken": false. So that won't work here.
I've also tried connecting a different way. Microsoft's PowerShell SDK has a VMConnectionInfo class that can be used as the connection info for a call to RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace. From there I can construct a PowerShell object in C#:
// Thanks, Microsoft, for making this constructor be internal
var constructorInfo = typeof(VMConnectionInfo).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    [ typeof(PSCredential), typeof(Guid), typeof(string), typeof(string) ]
) ?? throw new Exception("Cannot find the constructor");
var connectionInfo = (VMConnectionInfo)constructorInfo.Invoke([
    credential, // A PSCredential object constructed with the username and password of an administrator account on the VM
    vmId, // The VM's GUID
    null, // The VM's name. Null here since I'm using the GUID
    null // "configurationName: Configuration name of the VM session"
]);
using var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
using var ps = PowerShell.Create(runspace);

...and once I have the PowerShell object I can run commands like Start-Process to launch PsExec.exe on the VM with the parameters shown above.
But I still get the same error from PsExec:

PsExec could not start test.exe:
The requested operation requires elevation.

I'm unfamiliar with the Hyper-V WMI provider. Would this be possible to achieve through those interfaces?

Have you tried calling New-PSSession with explicit credentials of a local admin on the guest?

have you looked at Powershell Direct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/manage-windows-virtual-machines-with-powershell-direct you can just do Enter-PSSession -VMName YourVM or you can use Invoke-Command. I must say I think this is an exercise in frustration: GUI apps are designed to be used from the console, not via Powershell automation. You'd be much better off getting or writing a Windows service that can communicate via Powershell or command line directly.

@MathiasR.Jessen Yes. I edited the question to clarify that's what I was doing

@Charlieface As described in the question I've tried using at least one form of PowerShell Direct (the New-PSSession | Enter-PSSession method). I'm not sure if my C# code counts as another variant of that. And just to be sure, I tried Enter-PSSession -VMName as you suggested, which does get me in, but I still lack admin rights once I'm there.

@Charlieface I appreciate your suggestion to go the custom service route. I overlooked the possibility of invoking such a service via PowerShell. That would certainly fix the X in my X-Y problem. Thank you!

What happens if you provide -Credential with the creds of an admin of the guest OS.

@Charlieface When I execute Enter-PSSession -VMName "Windows 11" -Credential "guest admin user name" on the host then I get a credential prompt on the host asking for a password for that account on the guest OS. Then it lets me in, but PsExec fails with the permissions message when I execute it there, similar to as described in the question

Sounds like possibly a double-hop issue. You shouldn't really need PsExec to do whatever it is you are doing, the admiin should have enough permissions to do it directly. Also services cannot access the user console anyway, unless specifically allowed.

I am in fact running as a local administrator in the guest OS. I mistakenly concluded that I was not, but the following sanity check reveals my mistake and that I am in fact running as an administrator:
var isAdministrator = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
Console.WriteLine(isAdministrator);

The above code outputs "True" when compiled into an .exe that I copy to the guest VM and then execute remotely using the procedures described in the question.
So my issue lies elsewhere. Perhaps my issue is that I compiled my GUI test program ("test.exe") with an application manifest containing

<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />

When I specify uiAccess="false" then I'm able to launch my program in a PowerShell Direct session. My program still lacks UI access, but I suspect I'll be able to cross that bridge through a creative use of Win32 APIs.
